# Events for Sliders on Alternate Page Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and have a webpage with two `data-role=page` elements (one page for portrait orientation and one page for landscape orientation).

Each of these pages contains a `range/slider widget` and they should be synchronized together.

I am trying to subscribe to the `slidestop` event for each of these sliders.  **However, only the events from the slider that is first loaded are getting called (i.e. if the page opens in "portrait" mode, only the portrait slider's events will be called; if the page opens in "landscape" mode, only the landscape slider's events will be called).**

**Also, the second slider's value is not being updated when I call `.val(slideVal)`**

Here is a sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/69KbD/

When you load it, move the slider and notice that an alert appears. Then, resize the "Result" window by widening it --> you should see it switch to the "Landscape" page.  Now, move the slider and notice that no alert appears.

What am I doing wrong to initialize these event subscriptions?
Why isn't the second slider's value being updated?

---

Here is the JS code from the jsfiddle site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = init;
        function init() {
            // Switch page when orientation changes...
            $(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) { 
                if (e.orientation) {
                    if (e.orientation == "portrait") {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#pagePortrait");
                        $.mobile.navigate("#pagePortrait");     

                    } else if (e.orientation == "landscape") {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#pageLandscape");
                        $.mobile.navigate("#pageLandscape");
                    }
                }
            });


            // Update elements when slider changes...
            $("#rngPortrait").on("slidestop", function(event) {
                alert("Portrait Slidestop");

                var slideVal = $("#rngPortrait").val();
                $("#rngLandscape").val(slideVal);
                $("#txtPortrait").val(slideVal);
                $("#txtLandscape").val(slideVal);
            }); 

            $("#rngLandscape").on("slidestop", function(event) {
                alert("Landscape Slidestop");

                var slideVal = $("#rngLandscape").val();
                $("#rngPortrait").val(slideVal);
                $("#txtPortrait").val(slideVal);
                $("#txtLandscape").val(slideVal);
            }); 
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use the jQM page events instead of window.onload: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/69KbD/3/

Comment: @ezanker Thank you. You can add this as the solution if you'd like.